# Cannot declare square matrix with large rows/columns (1446) in ANSI C

Tags: c, matrix, memory, declare, ansi-c

I'm trying to declare an square matrix but I'm getting segfaults with values bigger than 1446 for rows/columns. I've found this value doing an "manual binary search".

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
boolean matrix[vertex][vertex];
memset(matrix, 0, sizeof(matrizAdjacencia[0][0]) * vertex * vertex);
```

The original run was trying to declare 32768*32768 positions. But it failed and then I started fixing low values until I found this 1446 value. The code fails before memset();

The boolean type is just an

```
typedef enum {true, false} boolean;
```

When running the program with gdb attached, the error generated is:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x00007fff5f3ff548
0x00007fff8e6a5fba in tzload ()
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `enum` variables are likely to correspond to `int`. Might have better luck with `char` (which can certainly hold all the values of that enum). 1446*1446*4 = over 8 megabytes.

Comment: Don't define your own `bool` type if possible, use `stdbool.h` instead . Your current type likely has `true==0` and `false==1` which WILL cause problems in the future.

Comment: I'm doing static allocation only due academic purposes. I know that dynamic allocation of memory is way better than this... Thanks for the stdbool.h tip. I will check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possibly due to the stack size limit in the system. See `ulimit -s` which in most systems of 8MB.

So, `1446 * 1446 * 4` is nearly `8MB` since **enum takes size of int**. So, you are not able to allocate more than the allowed stack size. The actual needed memory is `32768 * 32768 * 4` is nearly 4GB. You can probably use a `bitmap`, since you are dealing with `boolean` which reduces the needed memory. First changing the `int` to `char` reduces to `4GB / 4 = 1GB` and from `char` to bit field reduces to `1GB / 8 = 128MB`

Prefer using `malloc` or `calloc` for larger chunks of memory.

Comment: This should be the problem. I can confirm that max stack size is 8MB in my OS X system. I'm only using static matrix due academic purposes. So I just need to use an bitmap to allocate this portion of data?

Comment: Yes probably a `char[req_size]`. And u can use `malloc` or `calloc`. And each `char` represents 8 values.

Comment: Can you recommend some documentation about bitmap implementations? I've never used this approach.

Comment: Hope these SO questions help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384016/how-to-put-bits-into-a-character-array
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c